# How to pause my console on the desired key

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to pause my program on the 0x32, 0x33 and 0x34 key and make it work again on the 0x31 key, how can I? I used this code to pause on the 0x32 key, it's working, but I can't get it back to work on the desired key

Comment: `getchar` requires that the user commit their input with a press of the enter key. The path of least resistance is probably to use `getch` from the old DOS conio library. It's typically still supported under modern Windows systems.

Comment: Quick and dirty solution: `while (!AsyncKeyState(key1) && !AsyncKeyState(key2));` to wait for any of key1 or key2

Comment: how do i make it work again on the ''0x31'' key ?

Comment: The code I posted is meant to be used instead of `getchar` - so it should continue after the key is pressed. Disadvantage: Just polls and makes the processor warm until the key is pressed.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are avoiding synchronous input?

Comment: my program move mouse using mouse_event, i need only pause my program in key 0x32, 0x33 and 0x34, make it work again on the 0x31 key, how can I?

Comment: Again, is there a specific reason to poll asynchronous key states? Why not use a message loop, a timer for the `mouse_event`s, and synchronous keyboard handling?

Answer (score 1):

To summarize what @user4581301 suggested:

```
#include <conio.h>
...

if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x32) || GetAsyncKeyState(0x33) || GetAsyncKeyState(0x34)) {
    while (_getch() != 0x31)
        ;
}
```

Comment: to unpause on the 0x31 key, how do I?

Comment: @7VK sorry for the typo; fixed now.

Comment: is pausing, now I would just like to make it unpause and work again on the 0x31 key, the pause keys would like it to be 0x32, 0x33 and 0x34, and the unpause key to be 0x31

Comment: @7VK I've modified the code to pause on either 0x32, 0x33 or 0x34, and resume on 0x31. Does it work for you now?

Comment: it's just pausing, it's not returning to work on key 0x31

Comment: `_getch` requires that the console attached to the process is the foreground window. `GetAsyncKeyState`, on the other hand, [*"reflects the interrupt-level state associated with the hardware"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate), and will report the state regardless of the current foreground window. If the latter is a requirement, a low-level keyboard hook would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is a console application, I implemented the function you want through loop. If it's a desktop application, you can refer to my code logic.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<time.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
while (true) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(gun_keys[i]) && (gun != guns[i])) {
            gun = guns[i];

            system("cls");

            gun_delay = GetTime(gun->rpm);
            gun_index = 0;

            break;
        }
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DELETE)) //Bind key, what close this program
    {
        ExitProcess(-1); //Exit Process
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE) < 0) {
        if (!is_mouse_down) {
            is_mouse_down = true;
            if (gun != nullptr)
                gun_index = 0;
        }
        if (gun != nullptr && gun_index != gun->len) {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, long(gun->pattner[gun_index][0] * K), long(gun->pattner[gun_index][1] * K), 0, 0);
            ++gun_index;
            Sleep(gun_delay);
            continue;
        }
    }
    else
        is_mouse_down = false;

    if (_kbhit())//Checks if there is currently keyboard input and returns a non-zero value if there is, or 0 otherwise
    {
        int ch = _getch();
        if (ch == 0x32 || ch == 0x33 || ch == 0x34)
        {
            ch = _getch();//It waits for input and pauses the program
        }
        if (ch != 0x31)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (_kbhit())
                {
                    int ch = _getch();
                    if (ch == 0x31) break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        fflush(stdin);//Clear the input buffer
    }

    Sleep(150);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was kind of confused by this code, when I put it in my source, several numbers appeared on the console

Comment: This is just a sample, and you can't copy it directly into your program. My program outputs a number every 0.5 seconds to see if the program is running, and if you press (0x32) (0x33) (0x34) my program will pause the output of numbers and continue to output numbers when you press (0x31). This place( cout << i << endl;) outputs numbers, and you can put the parts of your program that need to be paused here.

Comment: look my code, how would you leave the code ?

Comment: I modified the code in my answer for your reference.

Comment: I don't know what could be happening, but it's just pausing, it's not working again on the 0x31 key

Comment: Could you *"- MSFT"* folks kindly stop pressuring users to accept a proposed answer that doesn't address the question? If you feel like something is missing from the question (and there is) then comment on the **question** rather than shelling out one low-quality answer after another. Wasting some more of my reputation to steer this proposed answer to where it belongs...

Comment: Is your 0x31 the number 1 key on your keyboard？